# Isn't there a file recovery program with GUI?

Tags: data-recovery

I want to recover deleted files from a sd card, but ways you can do it with the commands looks difficult,complicated and doens't give all the steps with the commands. Isn't there a easier way or less complicated way with program that has a GUI,that also works great?